# Debugging logic errors

Tags: html, css, hugo

Running the Hugo server with `--debug` shows all pages loading without any syntax errors, but they aren't displaying properly. I suspect that the site-heading.html file is part (if not all) of the problem. I've no idea how to debug logical errors with HTML code in Hugo.

Please point me to resources where I can learn how to debug my Hugo code.

Answer (score 0):

I learned how to insert stub code in html to print useful debugging information.

Answer (score 0):

Hugo has built-in Warning and Error functions, which you can insert into your templates or partials, so that Hugo prints debugging instructions when rendering the site.

See the [Hugo documentation](https://gohugo.io/functions/errorf/) for more information.